# Pocket API fails when re-trying to authorize user

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, oauth-2.0, pocket

I have the following issue with the [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/developer/) API in a Web app:

- At first the login flow works correctly and I can make authenticated calls.
- If the user reloads the page, when re-trying to authorize I get the following message:

[image]

- If I restart the server the authorization works once again (and fails after the first time). This makes me think that I'm not storing the authorization state correctly, but I could not find any information regarding this in the docs.

My app is written using Express on Node.js. The code is available [here](https://github.com/adrianp/bag), the components of interest being the [server entry-point](https://github.com/adrianp/bag/blob/master/src/server/index.js) and the [Pocket API endpoints](https://github.com/adrianp/bag/blob/master/src/server/pocket.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue was indeed not re-using the user access token; I now save it in a cookie and check for that before trying to re-authorize and everything seems to work OK (see [pull request](https://github.com/adrianp/bag/pull/11/files)).